# How can I change the UIButton "glow" color used when "Shows Touch On Highlight" is enabled?

Tags: ios, xamarin, uibutton, touch, highlight

I have a UIButton with "Shows Touch On Highlight" enabled in the storyboard. It applies a "white" glow to the button when clicked.

However, I have a light grey button and would like to change the glow color so that it's more visible.

I've tried setting the background image for the highlighted control state to black, but it doesn't seem to make a different to the glow. I can change the background color of the button---that all works.

What controls the glow color, if anything? Or do I have to do it manually if I need a different color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Shows Touch On Highlight" is a pure convenience, so you do have to do things manually if you want a different effect. Just supply a different image for the highlighted state, one that includes the desired "glow" drawing.

Answer (score 3):

Using a `setBackgroundImage` on the `UIButton` you can create a following extension that lets you to set a color for any state you want:

```
extension UIButton {
    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, for state: UIControlState) {
        let image = UIImage.image(with: color)
        let insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        let stretchable = image.resizableImage(withCapInsets: insets, resizingMode: .tile)
        self.setBackgroundImage(stretchable, for: state)
    }
}
```

Than you just need to set a background color for the `.highlighted` state:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor.red, for: .highlighted)
```

I just hope you don't mind getting your hands dirty with code, I'm not really sure how to do the same from storyboards (I'm not even sure you can do it).